# How to correctly inherit from class that returns other class based on condition?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, metaclass

I will first write the code and than the full explanation of what I am trying to achieve as it is easier this way:

```
global child_selector

class Base(object): 
  def __init__(self):
    self.extended_name = self.name + '_Base'


class Child1(Base): 
  def __init__(self):
    super(Child1, self).__init__()

  def print_my_name(self):
    print 'I am ChildOne'

class Child2(Base):

  def __init__(self):
    super(Child2, self).__init__()

  def print_my_name(self):
    print 'I am ChildTwo'

class ChildAsBaseSelector(object):
  def __new__(cls):
    if child_selector == 1:
      return Child1()
    elif child_selector == 2:
      return Child2()
    else:
      print 'No child selected'
```

Now if I create a class that inherits from Child1 or Child2 and has self.name as instance variable everything works as expected:

```
class Testing1(Child1):

  def __init__(self):
    self.name = 'Testing1'
    super(Testing1, self).__init__()

a = Testing1()
a.print_my_name() # 'I am ChlidOne'
print a.extended_name # 'Testing1_Base'
```

But if I create another class that will inherit directly from ChildAsBaseSelector() things become fishy:

```
class Testing2(ChildAsBaseSelector):

  def __init__(self):
    self.name = 'Testing2'
    super(Testing2, self).__init__()

child_selector = 1
a = Testing2() 
# Will raise AttributeError: 'Child1' object has no attribute 'name'
```

After reading the python documentation for '__new__()' I think the problem is because: 'If __new__() does not return an instance of cls, then the new instance’s __init__() method will not be invoked.' This does not really help since i don't know how to 'fix it'.

I also know I could do something like:

```
if child_selector == 1:
  ChildAsBaseSelector = Child1
if child_selector == 2:
  ChildAsBaseSelector = Child2
```

And than inherit directly from ChildAsBaseSelector. But I find this somehow not elegant and pushing python flexibility to its limits.
What I really want to do is have a class that will just return another class based on a condition, that I could use then to inherit from. Any hints? I guess metaclasses (a concept I am painfully trying to understand) would come in handy now.

Any tips appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just make `ChildAsBaseSelector` inherit from `Base` ? In your example, `super(Testing2, self).__init__()` will resolves to `object.__init__()` (so it wouldn't do what you expect), but - as you mentionned - it won't get called anyway because it's not in the `__mro__` of neither `Child1` nor `Child2`.

Anyway: having your `Base.__init__()` depending on a child class setting an attribute *before* invoking `super().__init__()` is bad design - if `Base` needs it, then it should be passed as an argument or have a usable default in `Base` itself.

Also if the only raison d'être of `ChildAsBaseSelector` is to create instances of either `Child1` or `Child1` based on a global / setting / whatever, just use a factory function... Not having a 'new' keyword is really a blessing.

Comment: 'Why don't you just make ChildAsBaseSelector inherit from Base?'. Because Base is intended for common methods and Child1 and Child2 have specific methods that i override (for example print_my_name). Inheriting from Base, would mean inheriting only the commons. Regarding the bad design part - There are many classes that will inherit from Child1 or Child2. They will all have a self.name variable that is used in Base to create self.extended_name (which is in fact a config file option). So having self.name set to a dummy value will raise a Config file has no option error

Comment: If `ChildAsBaseSelector` is only meant to instanciate other subclasses, then you don't care if it "only inherit the commons", since you'll never instanciate it. wrt/ the `name` attribute, if it's common to all your object hierarchy, then it should be passed as a required argument to `Base.__init__`, which would 1/ make for much more explicit code and 2/ avoid your AttributeError. Now I don't have all the context, so I can only comment on what you posted ;)

Comment: The big picture is that I am trying to refactor a huge amount of code. Expanding the question to fully cover all the problems I am trying to solve would make this post too verbose (and irrelevant to the question itself). For short, I do not want to use 'name' as required argument because there are other classes that inherit from Testing1, Testing2...also that need to use 'name' as set by the class they inherited from (Which is Child1 or Child2). Passing it as a required argument would mean overwriting it every time . Thank you for taking time to address my question.